# GUI hangs after clicking OK on popup in pysimplegui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm using pysimplegui to create a GUI for an application on python 3.9.5. I've programmed in some popup windows. My trouble is that once I do the popup in the event of an error and click ok, the GUI text boxes seem to hang. The buttons in the GUI still work, but none of the text inputs do. Here's a small section of the GUI code to illustrate:

```
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-serialPortGo-":
        try:
            serialPort = serial.Serial(values['-serialPortAddress-'],baudrate=values['-serialPortBR-'])
        except:
            window['-sessionLog-'].update(currentTime + ' Serial port connection error\n',append=True)
            window['-serialPortStatus-'].update('Not Connected')
            resp=sg.popup_ok('Serial port connection error. Check address and baudrate.',\
             title = 'Serial Port Error',font=font,background_color='white',text_color='red')
            continue
```

Attaching a couple of images too. Say I click "Go" without any serial port address or baudrate, which is wrong, I get the popup that says serial port error, which is what I expect. But, after I click OK on the popup, I can't seem to re-enter the correct serial port address as the GUI's text inputs have hung. I can still click those red and green buttons.[image: screenshot of the relevant part of the GUI]

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks nothing wrong in your small section of the GUI code, maybe in else where.

Comment: I looked into this in detail and it seems like this is an interaction between the popup and using a custom title bar for the window - if I leave use_custom_titlebar as False in the window declaration, I don't have this problem, but otherwise I do.